# Add to List value on HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, null-check

I'm populating a hashmap to have my objects grouped by one of their attributes.
I find it “ugly” to check whether the list (the value) exists before adding my object to it.

An example will be more explicit:

```
// Need a map to group Person by age.
// Person = {age: int}
Map<Integer, List<Person>> myHashMap = new HashMap();

for (Person person : persons) {
   int age = person.getAge();
   List<Person> personsOfSameAge = myHashMap.get(age);
   if (personsOfSameAge != null) {
       personsOfSameAge.add(person);
   } else {
       personsOfSameAge = new ArrayList();
       personsOfSameAge.add(person);
       myHashMap.put(age, personsOfSameAge);
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to code this?

```
myHashMap.addToValueListOrCreateValueList(myObject);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Java 8, your whole code could be written like that (as other fine answers proposed):

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> myHashMap = new HashMap();

for (Person person : persons) {
   myHashMap.computeIfAbsent(age,age->new ArrayList<Person>()).add(person);
}
```

But you could be even shorter by using a stream that collects into a `Map` with `Collectors.groupingBy()` :

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> myMap = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person:getAge));
```

---

As a side note, your actual Java 7 code could also be improved. 
Of course, not as much as with Java 8 but if you cannot use Java 8, this may be interesting.
In your actual code, this is duplicated :

```
personsOfSameAge.add(person);
```

And you use two conditional statements (`if` and `else`) while only `if` would be enough if you handle first the special case : no value in the `Map` .
Here is a modified version :

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Person person : persons) {
   int age = person.getAge();
   List<Person> personsOfSameAge = myHashMap.get(age);
   if (personsOfSameAge == null) {
       personsOfSameAge = new ArrayList();
       myHashMap.put(age, personsOfSameAge);
   }          
   personsOfSameAge.add(person);                
}
```

Comment: All hail Java8 !

Comment: God bless Java 8 but as I much used Java 7, I did an update for that :)

Comment: @Fundhor About your edit, it is more efficient if the `put()` is done a single time by key. And finally it produces the same result :)

Comment: In Java, the method reference uses double colons (::) , like so: Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is in Java 8:

```
List<Person> personsOfSameAge = myHashMap.computeIfAbsent(age,age->new ArrayList<Person>());
personsOfSameAge.add(person);
```

Or just

```
myHashMap.computeIfAbsent(age,age->new ArrayList<Person>()).add(person);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
  List<Person> newList = Optional.ofNullable( myHashMap.get(age)).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
  newList.add(person);
  myHashMap.put(age, newList);
```

Comment: You'll then need to add `newList` to the map.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Oh ya. Thanks for the catch. :)

Answer (score 1):

Though the question involves doing it in Java 8, I'm posting this as an alternate way.

You can use [MultiMap from Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

```
Multimap<String, Person> myHashMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Person person : persons) {
   myHashMap.put(person.getAge(), person);
}
```

However, you have to be aware of a difference: Java's map returns `null` for a non-existent key while the Google Guava's MultiMap returns an `empty List`.

From javadoc for **get(key)** of MultiMap

> Returns a view collection of the values associated with key in this multimap, if any. Note that when containsKey(key) is false, this returns an empty collection, not null.
>   Changes to the returned collection will update the underlying multimap, and vice versa